# Energy of elementary particles and Planck constant

Tags: energy, particle-physics, mass-energy, physical-constants

The energy of a photon is proportional to Planck's constant. Is this the case for the energy of other elementary particles?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#de_Broglie_relations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question that in the beginning of experimentally exploring quantum effects was an obvious one and was proposed by [de Broglie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#de_Broglie_relations) to be similar :

$E=ν*h$

Thus a frequency $ν$ can be defined for each particle, which has given rise to the term *matter wave.*

**Caution**:

It is  important to note  that  the so called "matter wave" is a confusing term. An individual particle's  energy $E$ is not spread out in space, as is very clearly seen in experiments with particles one at a time, in the same link:

[image: singl elect]

The interference pattern appears with an **accumulation**  of electrons diffracted through the same set up. The individual electrons leave a point on the screen, characteristic of a particle. The same is true with single photons at a time [as seen here .](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) .

Quantum mechanics is a probabilistic theory, not a deterministic one, one can only compute the probability of detecting a particle at (x,y,z) and all elementary particles are **point** particles.

Comment: Would E = hν also be applied to gravity if it existed?

Comment: @Jean-MichelTengang It is assumed to apply to gravitons, if gravitons exist.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the formula in the "wrong" way in terms of physics. The energy is proportional to the frequency. Plank constant is just the proportionality constant which depends on the system of units. We can take it to be one for example. And then it is obvious that the relationship is between energy and frequency.
The proportionality is a relationship between variables. It means that when one variable changes, the other one does too, and in a specific way. "Proportionality" between a variable and a constant does not make sense.

Comment: You are right.The question should be: "Does every particle have a frequency? If so, is its energy proportional to that frequency with a coefficient of proportionality equal to Planck's constant?". We could do without the first question if we already know that every particle has a frequency.

Comment: But my question was asked incorrectly and it was clarified in a comment above by G Smith: "I really think that the OP is just asking whether E=hν applies to particles other than photons."

Answer (score 0):

For an elementary particle, its energy levels $E$ are the eigenvalues of the Time Independent Schrödinger Equation:

$$\hat{H}\Psi=E\Psi$$

where $\hat{H}$ is the Hamiltonian (total energy) operator:

$$\hat{H}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+U(\mathbf{r})$$

with $\hbar=\frac{h}{2\pi}$.

It follows that these eigenvalues $E$ will always contain $h^2$:

$$E\propto h^2$$

As examples look up the energies for the $\text{1D}$ particle in an infinite box and the hydrogen atom.

For the $\text{P1DB}$:

$$E_n=\frac{n^2h^2}{8mL^2}$$

For $n=1,2,3,...$

For the Quantum Harmonic Oscillator:

$$E_n=(n+\frac12)\hbar \omega$$

For $n=1,2,3,...$

For the hydrogen atom:

$$E_n=-\frac{me^4}{32 \pi^2 \epsilon_0 \hbar^2 n^2}$$

For $n=1,2,3,...$

So in each of these cases the energy levels $E_n$ depend on the quantum number $n$ and $h$ or $\hbar$.

Comment: The question was about energies being *proportional to* Planck’s constant, not *containing* Planck’s constant.

Comment: I made a substantial edit to this answer.

Comment: The energy levels of hydrogen are not proportional to $h^2$ (which is what your $\propto$ means). The $h^2$ appears in the *denominator* of $E_n$. I really think that the OP is just asking whether  $E=h\nu$ applies to particles other than photons.

Comment: G. Smith, you have perfectly simplified my question with: "I really think that the OP is just asking whether E=hν applies to particles other than photons."